# Migrating from google-api-client 0.8.3 Authorizing Google::CalendarV3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

Attempting to migrate up from `google-api-client v0.8.3` and not finding an example of this use case for Google Calendar integration.

Application has a User model that allows users to authenticate via Google Outh and stores Google access and refresh tokens:

```rb
# simplified User class for example
class User
  attr_accessor :access_token
  attr_accessor :refresh_token
end
```

How do you provide the authorization to the calendar service object?

```rb
calendar = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
calendar.authorization = ????
```

ATTEMPT1: using Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets

```rb
s = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.new({
  web: {
    access_token: user.access_token,
    refresh_token: user.refresh_token,
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis/auth/calendar.events'],
    client_id: <client id for my app>,
    client_secret: <client secret for my app>
  })
calendar.authorization = s.to_authorization
calendar.list_calendar_lists
```

Result:  Google::Apis::ClientError insufficientPermissions: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

ATTEMP 2:  using Signet::OAuth2::Client

```rb
signet = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new( access_token: user.access_token, scope: 'https://www.googleapis/auth/calendar.events' )
calendar.authorization = signet
calendar.list_calendar_lists
```

Result:  Google::Apis::ClientError insufficientPermissions: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

The access token that I am using works perfectly in the code from v0.8.3.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My OAuth authorization was only authorizing the scope:  "https://googleapis/auth/calendar.events", but the capability to list the calendar lists requires the "https://googleapis/auth/calendar" scope.

Both authentication methods shown above work perfectly if you get the scopes correct.